# Constructor with custom classes as arguments, throws 'No matching function for call to...'

Tags: c++, constructor, default-constructor

I'm trying to create a constructor for a custom type, but for some reason, it's trying to call, what I'm guessing is the constructor in the constructor definition of another class.. Couldn't find anything which fits the same symptoms I'm having in any other questions, also as I may not know what I'm looking for.

When I call:

```
LatLngBounds clusterBounds(&boundsNorthEast, &boundsSouthWest);
```

in main.cpp, in LatLngBounds.cpp I get "No matching funciton for call to 'LatLng:LatLng()" thrown twice on the line for:

```
LatLngBounds::LatLngBounds(LatLng &newSouthWest, LatLng &newNorthEast)
```

Anyone got any ideas?

Drew J. Sonne.

IDE: Xcode 3.2 (Targeted to Debug 10.5)
OS: OSX 10.6
Compiler: GCC 4.2
Arch: x86_64

*main.cpp:*

```
std::vector<std::string> argVector;

... fill up my argVector with strings..

vector<double> boundsVector = explodeStringToDouble(argVector[i]);
LatLng boundsNorthEast(0, boundsVector[0], boundsVector[1]);
LatLng boundsSouthWest(0, boundsVector[2], boundsVector[3]);
LatLngBounds clusterBounds(&boundsNorthEast, &boundsSouthWest);
```

*LatLngBounds.h*

```
#ifndef __LATLNGBOUNDS
#define __LATLNGBOUNDS
#include "LatLng.h"
class LatLngBounds {
private:
    LatLng northEast;
    LatLng southWest;
public:
    LatLngBounds(LatLng&,LatLng&);
};
#endif
```

*LatLngBounds.cpp*

```
#include "LatLngBounds.h"
#include "LatLng.h"

LatLngBounds::LatLngBounds(LatLng &newSouthWest, LatLng &newNorthEast)
{
    this->southWest = newSouthWest;
    this->northEast = newNorthEast;
};
```

*LatLng.h*

```
#ifndef __LATLNGDEF
#define __LATLNGDEF
class LatLng {
public:
    LatLng(int,double,double);
private:
    double lat, lng;
    int id;
};
#endif
```

*LatLng.cpp*

```
#include "LatLng.h"
LatLng::LatLng(int newId, double newLat, double newLng)
{
    /* Grab our arguments */
    id = newId;
    lat = newLat;
    lng = newLng;
};
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your class you have two instances of LatLng objects.  In order to construct your object, the compiler also needs to construct them.

```
class LatLngBounds {
private:
    LatLng northEast;
    LatLng southWest;
```

Since class LatLng does not have a default constructor, you need to explicitly tell the compiler how to construct those object:

```
LatLngBounds::LatLongBounds( ..constructor args.. )
    : northEast( ..args for northEast constructor call ..),
      southWest( ..args for southWest constructor call ..)
{
}
```

Comment: Awesome. It was also the &'s in the function call, but this was what I couldn't find. Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

Your

```
LatLngBounds::LatLngBounds(LatLng &newSouthWest, LatLng &newNorthEast)
```

expects a arguments of type `LatLng`, passed implictly by reference.

The call `LatLngBounds clusterBounds(&boundsNorthEast, &boundsSouthWest);` passes two *pointers* (type `LatLng*`) instead.

Try instead:

```
LatLngBounds clusterBounds(boundsNorthEast, boundsSouthWest);
```

Comment: And, might I add, it would be a good idea to take the arguments by const reference.

Comment: Agreed, const LatLng& would be better.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure the error message you quoted is complete? It indicates, as you pasted, that there is no default empty constructor for LatLng, which the compiler will give you for free.

However, it looks like this line in main.cpp is wrong:

```
LatLngBounds clusterBounds(&boundsNorthEast, &boundsSouthWest);
```

The definition of the constructor for LatLngBounds are 2 non-const references to LatLng objects but you are passing 2 pointers to LatLng objects. Just pass them without the pointer:

```
LatLngBounds clusterBounds(boundsNorthEast, boundsSouthWest);
```

Comment: The compiler will not create a default constructor if there is any other user-defined constructor.